# VBA Variable Array Name?

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, dynamic

I would like to know if there a way to change array names while looping.

for example

```
For i= 1 to 4
    "array" & i()
Next i
```

array1 ,array2,array3,array4  are my 4 arrays.

Thanks

Comment: You can use double-dimensional arrays - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx - and then you can just change an index of required array easily.

Comment: Any time you find yourself needing to change the names of your variables is the time to re-think your approach.  If you really need to do this then consider storing your arrays in a Scripting Dictionary object with the "names" as keys.

Comment: If you edit this question to where it is clear what you're trying to do. (Code sample doesn't even seem to be trying to do anything useful) someone may be able to give you an alternative. As it is though, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I have 4 different arrays and i want to use the longest array among these 4 arrays.  so how do i get the longest array name?.

Comment: It might help if we knew more precisely what you are doing.  Then we may be able to suggest an alternate method.

Comment: What do you mean by longest array? Which array has the most elements?

Comment: If you use an array of arrays then you can loop over them and pick the largest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote my favourite StackOverflow answer:

> Short Answer:    No.
>   Long Answer:     Noooooooooooooo.